# Immutable fields without using builder pattern in Java

Tags: java, immutability

I'm trying to create `immutable` configuration by creating an interface and its implementation that is of `package private`. Only the `interface` is exposed to the client; the implementation is hidden and cannot be called outside of the package. `Interface` has `accessors` and `mutators` and a static method that instantiates its implementation and returns itself. Whenever `mutator` is called a new instance is being created passing all the fields in the constructor in order not to change the original values of the first object.

Here are my codes:

```
package com.example.api;

public interface Config {
    static Config newConfig() {
        return new ConfigImpl();
    }

    String host();
    Config host(String host);
    int port();
    Config port(int port);
    String database();
    Config database(String database);
    String user();
    Config user(String user);
    String password();
    Config password(String password);
}

package com.example.api;

class ConfigImpl implements Config {
    private final String host;
    private final int port;
    private final String database;
    private final String user;
    private final String password;

    public ConfigImpl() {
        this(null, -1, null, null, null);
    }

    public ConfigImpl(String host, int port, String database, String user, String password) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.database = database;
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String host() {
        return host;
    }

    @Override
    public Config host(String host) {
        return new ConfigImpl(host, port, database, user, password);
    }

    @Override
    public int port() {
        return port;
    }

    @Override
    public Config port(int port) {
        return new ConfigImpl(host, port, database, user, password);
    }

    @Override
    public String database() {
        return database;
    }

    @Override
    public Config database(String database) {
        return new ConfigImpl(host, port, database, user, password);
    }

    @Override
    public String user() {
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public Config user(String user) {
        return new ConfigImpl(host, port, database, user, password);
    }

    @Override
    public String password() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public Config password(String password) {
        return new ConfigImpl(host, port, database, user, password);
    }

}
```

Sample program that uses the API:

```
import com.example.api.Config;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Config config = Config.newConfig()
            .host("localhost")
            .port(7000)
            .database("mydb")
            .user("admin")
            .password("pwd");

        config.database("mydb2"); // won't change 'mydb'
        Config config2 = config.database("mydb2"); // needs to be assigned to new instance

        System.out.println(config.host() + "|" + config.port() + "|" + config.database() + "|" + config.user() + "|" + config.password());
        System.out.println(config2.host() + "|" + config2.port() + "|" + config2.database() + "|" + config2.user() + "|" + config2.password());
    }
}
```

This is working as expected:

```
localhost|7000|mydb|admin|pwd
localhost|7000|mydb2|admin|pwd
```

My concern is, is this a good design? Does it affect memory and performance since every mutator/setter creates a news instance?

I would prefer this over `builder pattern` if there's nothing wrong with my current design.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using this for database config, the performance is effectively irrelevant: the cost of creating these few objects is tiny compared to opening the database.

Comment: Personal preference, I would call the methods which return a new instance `with*`, or something else, to make it more clear that a new instance is returned.

Comment: Why would you create a new instance when an `accessor` is called? Wouldn't it be more appropriate to do so when a `mutator` is called?

Comment: @Andreas My bad. It should really be `mutator`. I've updated it.

Comment: @AndyTurner Originally I was using `with` but removed it later. IDK but when I saw `request` and `response` methods of Spark Framework, they look more concise and look closer to accessor with parameter being the difference. Anyway, it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm also considering to use this design to other configurations I might come up with.

Answer (score 0):

A builder should probably have a separate `build()` method to perform final set of operations e.g. validations on multiple fields that can't be addressed with just method signatures. It feels cleaner:

```
Config config = Config.newConfig()
            .host("localhost")
            .build();
```

The only concerning thing about your design is:

1. The amount of boilerplate code that has to be written by hand to make this work. Perhaps it's worth it in the end but if you plan to implement this for multiple types you should consider something to auto-generate the code e.g. [Lombok `@Builder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder).
2. Since you are not using regular `getXXX()` and `setXXX()` methods some frameworks that depend on the property method notation won't be able to process your class. Might be completely irrelevant in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have never been a fan of auto-generation library like `Lombok`. I prefer writing boilerplates where `Lombok` is particulary suited. I'd rather wait for `Records` which are coming in `Java 14`.

Comment: Yeah. I'm aware not using regular `getter` and `setter` methods might cause other frameworks not work if they depend on it. For now, yes, they are completely irrelevant in my case.

Comment: I'll think about that `build` in `builder pattern` as far as validations are concerned.